# file upload and extract its content and show it in view mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Anyone knows step by step execution of uploading file of any type say text file and get content extracted from it and let show that content on other view..Please let me know all the steps if anyone can...

Answer (score -1):

```
    You can achieve this by following below steps

   //Controller
    public ActionResult GetContent(string path)
    {
       return new FilePathResult(path, "application/octet-stream");
    }

    //View
    @Html.Action("GetContent","ControllerName", new { path = "~/path_of_the_file"" });
```

Comment: OP asking about File Upload, not about file download.